# Finding max value in col1 with respect to values in col2 of a list in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples, max

I am new to python. I want to find the max value from col2 with respect to the values 'men', 'women' and 'people' in col1 of the list. Like, `['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt'], ['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt']`and`['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt']` contain max values of col2 for men, women and people.

One possible solution is to convert this list of tuples to three separate arrays for men, women and people and then finding max value from all of the arrays. But, I want a better solution.

**Data:**

```
[['men', 2, '1945-Truman.txt']
['women', 2, '1945-Truman.txt']
['people', 10, '1945-Truman.txt']
['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt']
['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt']
['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt']
['men', 7, '1947-Truman.txt']
['women', 2, '1947-Truman.txt']
['people', 12, '1947-Truman.txt']
['men', 4, '1948-Truman.txt']
['women', 1, '1948-Truman.txt']
['people', 22, '1948-Truman.txt']
['men', 2, '1949-Truman.txt']
['women', 1, '1949-Truman.txt']
['people', 15, '1949-Truman.txt']
['men', 6, '1950-Truman.txt']
['women', 2, '1950-Truman.txt']
['people', 15, '1950-Truman.txt']
['men', 8, '1951-Truman.txt']
['women', 2, '1951-Truman.txt']
['people', 9, '1951-Truman.txt']
['men', 3, '1953-Eisenhower.txt']
['women', 0, '1953-Eisenhower.txt']
['people', 17, '1953-Eisenhower.txt']]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` is a good one, but you can just use `max` and `lambda`:

```
men = max(data, key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == 'men' else 0)
women = max(data, key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == 'women' else 0)
people = max(data, key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == 'people' else 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `pandas` packages.
By defining the data frame :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['men', 2, '1945-Truman.txt'],
                   ['women', 2, '1945-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 10, '1945-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt'],
                    ['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 7, '1947-Truman.txt'],
                   ['women', 2, '1947-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 12, '1947-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 4, '1948-Truman.txt'],
                   ['women', 1, '1948-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 22, '1948-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 2, '1949-Truman.txt'],
                   ['women', 1, '1949-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 15, '1949-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 6, '1950-Truman.txt'],
                   ['women', 2, '1950-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 15, '1950-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 8, '1951-Truman.txt'],
                   ['women', 2, '1951-Truman.txt'],
                   ['people', 9, '1951-Truman.txt'],
                   ['men', 3, '1953-Eisenhower.txt'],
                   ['women', 0, '1953-Eisenhower.txt'],
                   ['people', 17, '1953-Eisenhower.txt']])
```

Then

```
df.groupby([0], sort=False)[1].max()
```

return

```
0 
men       12
women      7
people    49
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a list of lists such as:

```
lst=[['men', 2123, '1945-Truman.txt'],
['women', 2, '1945-Truman.txt'],
['people', 10, '1945-Truman.txt'],
['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt'],
['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt'],
['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt'],
['men', 7, '1947-Truman.txt'],
['women', 2, '1947-Truman.txt']]
```

Then you can use the following code.

```
max_men=0
max_women=0
max_people =0
for item in lst:
    if((item[0]=="men") and (item[1]>max_men)):
        max_men=item[1]
    elif((item[0]=="women") and (item[1]>max_women)):
        max_women=item[1]
    elif((item[0]=="people") and (item[1]>max_people)):
        max_people=item[1]

print max_men
print max_women
print max_people
```

This will go into each list within the bit list called `lst` and find the max value for men, women, and people.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a set out of the first column and find the maximum value afterwards:

```
data = [
    ['men', 2, '1945-Truman.txt'],
    ['women', 2, '1945-Truman.txt'],
    ...
]

keys = set([col[0] for col in data])

for k in keys:
        print (k, max([col[1] for col in data if col[0] == k]))
```

Returns:

```
women 7
people 49
men 12
```

Comment: Great answer. Really easy to understand. It would be great if the name of the .txt file(col3) is also printed in output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas`, I suppose **data** is a list of list:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[df.groupby([0])[1].idxmax()]

        0   1                2
3     men  12  1946-Truman.txt
5  people  49  1946-Truman.txt
4   women   7  1946-Truman.txt
```

For a result in the same format:

```
df.loc[df.groupby([0])[1].idxmax()].values.tolist()

[['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt'], ['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt'], ['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
new_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
new_final_data = [max(b, key=lambda x:x[1]) for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt'], ['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt'], ['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt']]
```

Or, a dictionary with each key the type of individual:

```
new_final_data = {a:max(b, key=lambda x:x[1]) for a, b in new_data}
```

Output:

```
{'women': ['women', 7, '1946-Truman.txt'], 'men': ['men', 12, '1946-Truman.txt'], 'people': ['people', 49, '1946-Truman.txt']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
men = [t for t in yourlist if t[0] == 'men']
women = [t for t in yourlist  if t[0] == 'women']
people = [t for t in yourlist  if t[0] == 'people']
sorted(men, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0][1]
sorted(women, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0][1]
sorted(people, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0][1]
```